# Align fields in form using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap` to design web pages. I have two major problems.Firstly, can't really figure out how to align fields in a `form`.Secondly, adjusting the fields(the width height etc..) in a `form tag`. Do I have to use `css` for each and every field? I tried doing that, but then the alignment gets messed up. Here's my code .

```
            <div class="container">

        <form class="form-inline">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control">In Out Specifier</label>
                <select  class="form-control" id="processInOutSpecifier" name="inOutSpecifier" >
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control" id="callDateLabel">Call Date</label>
                <select  class="form-control" id="callDate" name="callDate" >
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control" id="processCallDateFormatLabel" >Call Date Format</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="callDate" name="callDateForamt">
                    <option>yyyy-MM-dd</option>
                    <option> yyyy/MM/dd</option>
                    <option> MM-dd-yyyy</option>
                    <option>  MM/dd/yyyy</option>
                    <option> dd-MM-yyyy</option>
                    <option> dd/MM/yyyy</option>
                    <option>dd/MM/yy</option>
                    <option>  MM/dd/yy</option>
                    <option> yyMMdd</option>
                    <option>  MMddyy</option>
                    <option> dd.MM.yy</option>
                    <option> MM.dd.yy</option>
                    <option>MM.dd.yy</option>
                    <option>dd/MM</option>
                    <option>dd-MM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control">Call Time</label>
                <select class ="form-control" id="callTime" name="callTime" >
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br><br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control" >Call Time Format</label>
                <select id="callTimeFormat" class="form-control" name="CalltimeFormat">
                    <option>HH:MM:SS/12 HOUR</option>
                    <option>HH:MM:SS/24 HOUR</option>
                    <option> HH:MM/12 HOUR</option>
                    <option> HH:MM/24 HOUR</option>
                    <option> HH:MM/AMPM</option>
                    <option>HHMM/24 HOUR</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control" >Trunk </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="processTrunk" placeholder="Trunk">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control" >Duration </label>
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" id="processDuration" placeholder="Duration">
            </div>                      
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/core972/SMkZV/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/SMkZV/128/),

```
<div class="container">
    <form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="username" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="username" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" autocapitalize='off' name="username" title="Enter username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="password" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what about placing the labels right next to the input fields ?

Comment: The label text is hidden because you have used this class="sr-only".

Comment: I am able to align 3 to four fields. The problem arises when I want 3 labels and alongside each label a text input. All this in one line. Aligning this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMkZV/129/)**

```
<form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-horizontal col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="firstname" class="form-control reg_name" type="text" name="firstname" title="Enter first name" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="lastname" class="form-control reg_name" type="text" name="lastname" title="Enter last name" placeholder="Last name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="username" class="form-control reg_name" type="text" autocapitalize='off' name="username" title="Enter username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="password" class="form-control reg_name" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Form with label **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMkZV/134/)**

For more details refer **[Bootstrap Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/SMkZV/132/)**

```
    <form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname"
                       title="Enter first name"
                       placeholder="First name"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname"
                       title="Enter last name"
                       placeholder="Last name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname"
                       title="Enter first name"
                       placeholder="Username"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
                <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname"
                       title="Enter last name"
                       placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

This another style you can create form **[Check this DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/L17m2boq/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sibinva/0dvtLLf1/)

```
<form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label for="firstname" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input id="firstname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="firstname"
                   title="Enter first name"
                   placeholder="First name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label for="lastname" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input id="lastname" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" type="text" name="lastname"
                   title="Enter last name"
                   placeholder="Last name"/>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" autocapitalize='off' name="username"
               title="Enter username"
               placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only"></label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password"
               title="Enter password"
               placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```